# Can not remove console.log with strip-loader

Tags: webpack

I am trying to use webpack 2's strip-loader to remove console.log in the final bundle.js, here is my config:

```
 var WebpackStrip = require('strip-loader');
 module: {

 loaders: [
  { test: /\.js$/, loader: WebpackStrip.loader('debug', 'console.log') }
 ]...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert it as a rule:

```
 module: {
      rules: [
        {test: /\.js$/, use: ['strip-loader?strip[]=debug,strip[]=console.log', @ngtools/webpack'], exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]}
        {test: /\.scss$/, use: ['raw-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']}
        ...etc
      ]
    }
```

You won't need the:

```
var WebpackStrip = require('strip-loader');
```